# Utility for maxing out file system memory

Tags: android

Does anyone know if there is an app that exists that will fill up the internal phone memory or SD Card memory to help with testing app functionality under full memory conditions?  If anyone here is familiar with BREW development I'm looking for the Android equivalent of maxfilecnt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply open a file and write to it until it fails:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
while(true)
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to write the code if I was going to do it myself, but I was hoping that there was already a utility out there to do this.  Seems surprising that Google wouldn't offer something like this as part of the SDK.